# Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, public-key-encryption

While using OpenSSL on Windows:

`openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024 -->`

Created successfully

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 365 
---->
```

Showing error message as

> unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

Comment: All answers show that somehow one must reference the config file openssl.cnf.. BUT nobody mentions what config file,?? who creates it, ?? what is its content?

Answer (score 198):

After installing OpenSSL I was required to create a new environment variable:

- Name: `OPENSSL_CONF`
- Value: `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf`

In powershell:

```
$env:OPENSSL_CONF = "${env:ProgramFiles}\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf"
```

This value differs from previous installation versions (as seen in a previous edit of this post).  Also, don't forget to add the openssl binary folder `${env:ProgramFiles}\OpenSSL` to your Path.

Comment: On version 1.0.1j I had to use `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg` instead.

Comment: Or C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg in 64bits systems

Comment: Or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\ssl\openssl.cfg` for those already with git.

Comment: where/how are you setting this value?

Comment: This would put it in your user's startup environment:
`SETX OPENSSL_CONF c:/libs/openssl-0.9.8k/openssl.cnf`

Comment: On my windows installation the path was "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\share\openssl.cnf"

Comment: to find the path, the best way is to first look for the directory where the openssl binary is stored. To do so, run the following command `(get-command openssl).Path` and then look for the openssl.cnf file within that directory (directly in this folder, or in share/ssl/bin subfolder)

Comment: For me, the conf file from Git is at `c:\Program Files\Git\usr\ssl\openssl.cnf`

Answer (score 102):

You should specify the absolute path to the config, something like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -config "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cnf" ...
```

Comment: -config C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cnf

Comment: In Version 1.0.1e downloaded from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html there is only the file `openssl.cfg` present in the bin directory after installation. But with this file it seems to work anyway.

Comment: If you're using the OpenSSL provided with Git then you might try `-config "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\ssl\openssl.cnf"`

Comment: openssl:Error: '-config' is an invalid command. how do you guys set it?

Comment: @kewlbfy see @Kosar answer below for where to use the `-config` flag, this worked for me

Answer (score 43):

In Windows 10, no need to restart nor run in Administrator's mode but instead set openssl config like so:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\share\openssl.cnf
```

Of course, if you are using `GnuWin32`

Answer (score 28):

The **only** thing that worked for me in this situation was the **self-created** *openssl.cnf* **file**.

Here are the basics needed for this exercise (edit as needed):

```
#
# OpenSSL configuration file.
#

# Establish working directory.

dir                         = .

[ ca ]
default_ca                  = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
serial                      = $dir/serial
database                    = $dir/certindex.txt
new_certs_dir               = $dir/certs
certificate                 = $dir/cacert.pem
private_key                 = $dir/private/cakey.pem
default_days                = 365
default_md                  = md5
preserve                    = no
email_in_dn                 = no
nameopt                     = default_ca
certopt                     = default_ca
policy                      = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName                 = match
stateOrProvinceName         = match
organizationName            = match
organizationalUnitName      = optional
commonName                  = supplied
emailAddress                = optional

[ req ]
default_bits                = 1024          # Size of keys
default_keyfile             = key.pem       # name of generated keys
default_md                  = md5               # message digest algorithm
string_mask                 = nombstr       # permitted characters
distinguished_name          = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions              = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name             Prompt string
#-------------------------    ----------------------------------
0.organizationName          = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_max            = 40
localityName                = Locality Name (city, district)
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min             = 2
countryName_max             = 2
commonName                  = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)
commonName_max              = 64

# Default values for the above, for consistency and less typing.
# Variable name             Value
#------------------------     ------------------------------
0.organizationName_default  = My Company
localityName_default        = My Town
stateOrProvinceName_default = State or Providence
countryName_default         = US

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints            = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier      = keyid:always,issuer:always

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints            = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Having tried every other solution listed here, this one worked for me. Once the config is created (in the openssl.exe directory) you can then run `openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 365 -config openssl.cnf`

Answer (score 21):

In windows , [**Similar scenario**]

I was facing the same problem But It was during requesting for Certificate Signing Request.

I did the below , It Worked for me.

Once OpenSSL installed, Ran command prompt as administrator after the system reboot.[for the best I did both.. run as admin and system reboot]

did,
1.[Error Case]

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

WARNING: can't open config file: C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cnf
AND
Unable to load config info from C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cnf

2.[Worked with Warning]

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin> openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
```

> [Warning message]: WARNING: can't open config file: C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cnf

But prompted me for the [Pass Phrase](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) for server.key 
It **worked** for me.

I referred,This [link](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) for my assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, the link you provided helped me very much: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Answer (score 12):

After installing OpenSSL, you need to restart your computer and use `Run As Administrator`. Then its works.

Answer (score 12):

For me on Windows 8, I simply found openssl.cnf file and copied it on the C drive. then:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config C:\openssl.cnf
```

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

With the GnuWin32 tools I found the openssl.cnf under C:\gnuwin32\share

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\gnuwin32\share\openssl.cnf
```

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 7 I didn't have to restart, simply run command prompt in administrator mode.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I need to set the path of **openssl.cnf** file manually on the command using `config` option. So the command

```
openssl req -x509 -config "C:\Users\sk\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\openssl.cnf" -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -nodes -days 900
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **Win32 OpenSSL v1.1.0g**, setting up this environment variable:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\cnf\openssl.cnf
```

Before running this command with *"server.key"*, successfully creating *"server.csr"*:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Answer (score 3):

On the basic question of why openssl is not found:
Short answer:Some installation packages for openssl have a default openssl.cnf pre-included.  Other packages do not.
In the latter case you will include one from the link shown below;
You can enter additional user-specifics --DN name,etc-- as needed.

From https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/config.html,I quote directly:

"OPENSSL LIBRARY CONFIGURATION

Applications can automatically configure certain aspects of OpenSSL using the master OpenSSL configuration file, or optionally an alternative configuration file. The openssl utility includes this functionality: any sub command uses the master OpenSSL configuration file unless an option is used in the sub command to use an alternative configuration file.

To enable library configuration the default section needs to contain an appropriate line which points to the main configuration section. The default name is openssl_conf which is used by the openssl utility. Other applications may use an alternative name such as myapplication_conf. All library configuration lines appear in the default section at the start of the configuration file.

The configuration section should consist of a set of name value pairs which contain specific module configuration information. The name represents the name of the configuration module. The meaning of the value is module specific: it may, for example, represent a further configuration section containing configuration module specific information. E.g.:"

So it appears one must self configure openssl.cnf according to your
Distinguished Name (DN), along with other entries specific to your use.

[Here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/openssl.cnf) is the template file from which you can generate openssl.cnf
with your specific entries.

[One Application](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/enterprise-developer/ed40pu3/ED-VS2017/HROSSROPEN02.html) actually has a demo installation that includes a demo .cnf file.

Additionally, if you need to programmatically access .cnf files, you can
include appropriate headers --openssl/conf.h-- and parse your .cnf files
using

```
CONF_modules_load_file(const char *filename, const char *appname,
                            unsigned long flags);
```

[Here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/CONF_modules_load.html) are docs for "CONF_modules_load_file";

Comment: Except the dead links ... this answer was great, since it shed a light on the why the file didn't exist *sometimes*. Searching my machine I found several openssl.cnf files which came with other software, e.g. GitHub, VisualStudio etc, and a copy of any of those worked well, but I had to include -config openssl.cnf in my openssl command line as well. Also note, that a (obviously irrelevant) warning "WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf" appeared, which isn't too surprising on a Windows machine. Nevertheless the certificates were created properly.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Powershell:

```
$env:OPENSSL_CONF = "${env:ProgramFiles}\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me put variable before calling did the trick:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=/usr/ssl/openssl.cnf openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 365
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Windows 7:

```
WARNING: can't open config file: C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
Unable to load config info from C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
```

The reason was removed `OpenSSL-Win32` directory without using deinstallator, so not all components was properly removed from system.
I had to **remove environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF`** manually.

Some openssl binaries, e.g. installed with git, does not need `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable, but if this environment variable exists it must lead to valid file.