# Can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl

I have installed OpenSSL 64. I want to use a certificate for my nodejs https server. I ran the following command:

```
openssl genrsa -out subdomain.domain.com.key 1024
```

But I have got the error:

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
.........++++++
.........................................++++++
unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

How can I resolve it?
Is this the right command?

Comment: Create a text file and call it openssl.cnf. Sample content of the file: http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates#SSLCert-4

Comment: Stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43630802/4217744

Answer (score 298, accepted):

The solution is running this command:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
```

or

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=[path-to-OpenSSL-install-dir]\bin\openssl.cfg
```

in the command prompt before using `openssl` command.

Let `openssl` know for sure where to find its `.cfg` file.

Alternatively you could set the same variable `OPENSSL_CONF` in the Windows environment variables.

NOTE: This can happen when using the [OpenSSL binary distribution from Shining Light Productions](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) (a compiled + installer version of the official OpenSSL that is free to download & use). This distribution is "semi-officially" linked from OpenSSL's site as a "service primarily for operating systems where there are no pre-compiled OpenSSL packages".

Comment: Make sure you create a user variable. In my case, creating a system var doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Does not work and I've checked the OPENSSL_CONF var in the console and it's set.

Comment: If you are using a path with spaces, try wrapping it with quotes: `set "OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL Win32\bin 123\openssl.cfg"`

Comment: Also note that, as most cross-platform open-source crapyware do, having unicode characters in the path will create problems.

Comment: For me it was required to use double slashes: `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\\Projects\\Web\\apache\\conf\\openssl.cnf`

Comment: @birken25 If creating this as a system var, you will have to get a new cmd prompt. Existing cmd sessions do not update their environment with changes to system variables.

Comment: @matty Good tip, maybe that was my issue

Comment: I had to change `cfg` in the above command to `cnf`

Answer (score 25):

I've SSL on Apache2.4.4 and executing this code at first, did the trick:
 
`set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\openssl.cnf`

then execute the rest codes..

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 2008 R2 with Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_0c +1

Answer (score 11):

> /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

A path like this means the program has been compiled with either Cygwin or MSYS. If you must use this `openssl` then you will need an interpreter that understands those paths, like Bash, which is provided by Cygwin or MSYS.

Another option would be to download or compile a Windows Native version of `openssl`. Using that the program would instead require a path like

```
C:\Users\Steven\ssl\openssl.cnf
```

which would be better suited for the Command Prompt.

Comment: No. I think it means it was compiled with OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl". Mine was compiled with cl.exe `openssl version -f
compiler: cl -D_USING_V110_SDK71_ [..]`.

Answer (score 8):

## SOLUTION!

just set **`-config`** parameter location correctly, i.e :

```
openssl ....................  -config C:\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf
```

Comment: This works for "openssl req" but not for "openssl pkcs12". The environment variable worked for both. It is strange that the pkcs12 option does not include the -config switch.

Comment: Funny... `openssl req` ignores `-config` here (Apache/2.4.10 Win64) but setting `OPENSSL_CONF` works fine.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I used the binaries from Shining Light and the environment variables were already updated. But still had the issue until I ran a command window with elevated privileges.

When you open the CMD window be sure to run it as Administrator. (Right click the Command Prompt in Start menu and choose "Run as administrator")

I think it can't read the files due to User Account Control.

Comment: Running the commands as Administrator and doing `set OPENSSL_CONF=` fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what is the difference between .cfg & .cnf
In my server I couldn't find .cfg or .cnf
I had created a new file for the [same](http://www.tbs-certificats.com/openssl-dem-server-cert-thvs.cnf) and placed it in the following folder `/usr/local/ssl/bin`

executed the

```
.\openssl genrsa -des3 -out <key name>.key 2048
```

went great..

Answer (score 1):

Simply install Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2a or Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2a, you can download these from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Works out of the box, no configuration needed.

Comment: That's where I downloaded from, and was going to say that it has the problem described by the OP, but after following advice (from Xero accounting) to restart the computer after installing, I found that it worked with no issues.