# I keep on getting the error: Unable to load config info from c:openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf When using open ssl

Tags: openssl

When using this command: `openssl req -new -x509 -days 3652 -key customerCA.key -out customerCA.crt`
I get an error: `Unable to load config info from c:openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

I have opensll installed on: `C:\Users\nicko\Desktop\cluster-csr\feb9\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\` and the opensll .cnf file is under `the openssl-0.9.8k_X64:

[Proof of file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB4qW.png)

I also made an enviroment variable:

[Proof of env variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7M0T.png)

I've looked at [Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459078/unable-to-load-config-info-from-usr-local-ssl-openssl-cnf-on-windows) (another stackoverflow post) and nothing there helps. If anyone has any idea why this is happening, I'd apreciate any answer.

Comment: Confirm the env var setting _at the point you run the program_ with `set openssl_conf` in CMD or `gci env:openssl_conf` in PS. Meta: this isn't related to programming, so it probably belongs on superuser or maybe security.SX instead.

Comment: When I use the command set openssl_conf it says that the enviroment variable `openssl_conf` is not defined. I might have been stupid and not completely understood what you meant by "at the point you run the program." Should I type in the command inside the directory: C:\Users\nicko\Desktop\cluster-csr\feb9\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>, or no?

Comment: The directory doesn't matter. You said you 'used' the command `openssl req -new blah blah`. You can only give a command like that to a process that accepts commands, which on Windows is normally either the traditional 'command prompt' (CMD) or the newer PowerShell (PS). (In general you can also put some commands in the 'start' box, but for openssl you wouldn't have been able to see the output, and you did see the output.) My point was to check the env var setting _in that process_ -- the one you ran `openssl` in -- because each process has separate env var settings. ...

Comment: ... That process (CMD or PS) may very well currently be in your directory because you wanted to run `openssl` without having the directory in your PATH. If so that constraint applies to the `openssl` command but not the `set` (or `gci`) command. If you did indeed do the `set` in that CMD process, you've proven it does not have the env var setting you think it has. (1) did you change the env var setting recently, and was the CMD created before then, or created from some other process that was created before then? (2) did you do other things in this CMD process before the `openssl`?

Comment: Ah yes. All I had to do was open up a fresh cmd prompt and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks!